# Use response of 2 different AJAX calls (in their own functions) in a third function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function tinyurl() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://xxxxxxxxxxx/',
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(response) {
            welcomemsg(response.id);
        }
    });
}

function namie() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxxxx.com/names?user=random,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            welcomemsg(data);
        }
    });
}

function welcomemsg() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxxx.com/posts?walmessage=Hello ' + data.name + ' your post has been posted '+ response.id +',
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function() {
        }
    });
}
```

I want to get the response of the `tinyurl` and `namie` functions, and then use them in the function `welcomemsg`.

I tried using parameters but was not successful.

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an error, or a false reult? There were some misplaced apostrophes that I corrected in your code. Make sure the same thing isn't living in your real code.

Comment: I am not able to pass response of tinyurl and namie in function welcomemsg

Comment: @meagar sir please describe in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the promises being returned by `$.ajax`.

```
var p1 = jQuery.ajax({url:'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://xxxxxxxxxxx/', dataType:'script'})

var p2 = jQuery.ajax({url:'https://xxxxxx.com/names?user=random', dataType:'jsonp'})

$.when(p1, p2).then(function (response, data) {
  welcomemsg(response[0], data[0]);
});

function welcomemsg(response, data){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url:'https://xxxxx.com/posts?walmessage=Hello ' + data.name + ' your post has been posted '+ response.id ,
    dataType:'script',
    success:function(){
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i erased my comment after further reviewing your code. Normally, I would just call `welcomemsg()` in the success parameter function of the ajax calls. This is just formatted differently but appears to be similar. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: @Dutchie432 In *which* success parameter function? There are two, and you can only invoke `welcomemsg` after *both* original calls are finished.

Comment: @meagar can we make response as var ?  Like var userid = respinse.id ;

Comment: @AnandShinde And then, what, invoke `welcomemsg` twice, and check whether each variable is set? Or, are you going to nest your AJAX requests so that they run in serial instead of in parallel?